# Tips for golfing in Knight

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) is the [Language of the Month for August 2022](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25002/language-of-the-month-for-august-2022-knight), and I noticed that it didn't have a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) page, so here it is!

I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Knight (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post only one tip per answer.

Answer (score 4):

Variables in Knight consist of a lowercase letter followed by additional lowercase letters or numbers, but not uppercase letters. This means that you don't need a space between a variable and a function call -- e.g.

```
Oa Ob
OaOb
```

But you can't do

```
O+a1
```

because the `1` will be parsed as part of the variable name. To get around this, swap the argument order:

```
O+1a
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ASCII` function in Knight, if given a string, returns the ASCII value of just the first character of a string; if given a number, it returns the ASCII character with that code point. This means that `ASCII (ASCII s)` will return the first character of string `s`. You can use this along with `GET` to iterate through a string:

```
;=pP;=i~1W<=i+1iLpO Gp i 1
;=pP Wp;O A Ap=pGp 1Lp
```

Here's the code snippets written out in easier to understand format, with basically equivalent Python code on the side:

```
;= p PROMPT                         # p = input()
;= i ~1                             # i = -1
 WHILE (< (= i (+1 i)) (LENGTH p)   # while (i = i+1) < len(p):
   OUTPUT (GET p i 1)               #   print(p[i:i+1])

;= p PROMPT                         # p = input()
 WHILE p                            # while p != "":
 ;OUTPUT (ASCII (ASCII p))          #   print(p[0])
  = p (GET p 1 (LENGTH p))          #   p = p[1:len(p)+1]
```

Technically, the call to `Gp 1Lp` is undefined since `+ 1 LENGTH p` is outside of the bounds of the string `p`. In order to make it fully spec-compliant, it would have to be

```
;=pP Wp;O A Ap=pGp 1-Lp 1
```

However, the first version works within the C TIO.

*Edit:* [Using @Sampersand's suggestions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251090/113573), you could alternatively do

```
;=pP Wp;O GpF1=pSpF1""
```

Which is the same number of characters but spec-compliant. In this case, we can additionally use the fact that `OUTPUT` returns a falsy value to shorten it to

```
;=pP Wp=pSpO GpF1T""
```

Which saves two bytes.

Comment: It also works in the JS interpreter so it should be good

Comment: To get the first character, you can do `Gsome_stringF1`—get the substring starting at `F` (ie `0`) of length `1`. To get the rest of the characters, you can do `Ssome_stringF1""`—return a new string with the range `F..F+1` (ie `0..1`) replaced with an emoty string

Answer (score 3):

## Use coercion

For example, in the case that `+` receives a string as the first and a number as the second arg, it will coerce the second one to a string and concatenate them. However, if you do it vice versa, with a number as the first and a string as the second, it will convert the second to a number and add the two. This means that you can use `+0` to convert a string to a number, and `+""` to convert a number to a string.

However, sometimes, `+0` can be one byte shorter! `E`, the evaluate function, will evaluate its argument as Knight code. So given a number-string, it will convert to a number. Often, however, this will cost 1 or 2 bytes due to whitespace being needed.

With `*`, if the first argument is a string and the second a number, it will repeat the string n times instead of multiplying. In the case of num+str, it will coerce the string to a number. And with str+str, it will coerce the second to a number and repeat the first string that many times.

However, with `-`, `/`, `^`, and `%`, if the first is a number, the second will be converted to a number. But if the first is a string, it's undefined behavior.

Some other operators like `<` and `>` will also coerce - [see the spec](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/blob/master/specs.md).

Comment: I think almost every function does type coercion except for `?` (comparison).

Answer (score 3):

## Using `&` and `|` instead of `IF`

Unless you need both the if true and if false clauses of `IF`, you can simply use `&` or `|`.

Instead of `Ifoo bar <whatever>`, you can do `&foo bar`. Likewise, instead of `Ifoo <whatever> bar` (or `I!foo bar <whatever>`), you can do `|foo bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the assignment operator in Knight returns the assigned value, you can chain together definitions if, for example, you want to create multiple variables with the same value:

```
;=a 0;=b 0=c 0
=a=b=c 0
```

Comment: You should edit the LOTM page with links to your tips in the "List of relevant tips posted in August 2022" section.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious, all functions can be abbreviated to a single uppercase character. For example:

```
OUTPUT 1
O 1
```

You also can remove the space between the function and the parameter:

```
O1
```

But if you want to nest function calls, you need to put a space between them:

```
OP   # Parsed as a single function "OP", which is equivalent to "OUTPUT"
O P  # Parsed as "OUTPUT PROMPT"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use `T` or `F` instead of `1` or `0` to save a character

Examples:

#### Save a byte when initializing to 0

Instead of `;=n 0` you can do `;=nF`, but this will require you to ensure that you're coercing `a` later on. But, if you're using `n` as a counter, you can simply do `W>100=n+1n`, which'll coerce the initial `F` to `0`.

#### Getting the first character of a string

Instead of `Gs 0 1`, you can do `GsF1`—since all arguments to `G` are coerced to the appropriate types, this'll always work.

#### Getting the rest of a string

Instead of `Ss 0 1 ""` (set the range `0..0+1` to an empty string), you can do `SsF1""`. This works in a similar fashion to `G`

Comment: This can also save a byte or two when doing arithmetic. For example, `-n 1` (where `n` is an integer) can be shortened to `-nT`.